# Hide a div when a link is clicked - PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to make a div disappear anytime a link is clicked on php,
this is my code

```
<?php
                  echo '<div id="content">
                          <table width="300">
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                               <a href="calendar.php" style="color: red" target="_top">'.$name.'</a>
                                 </td>
                               </tr>
                           </table> </div>';
     //when this is clicked, hide the 'content' div 
    echo '<a href="javascript:;" id="next">next</a>';

?>
```

this is my script code that is not doing anything for now

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#next').live("click",function(){
     $('#content').hide();
});
 </script>
```

How can I hide the `<div id="content">` when the link 'next' is clicked? Any suggestion will help thanks!

Comment: `$('#next').click(function(){ $('#content').hide(););`?

Comment: yes that is my current script , but it seems not to work

Comment: that is not your current script, at least, not what you've shown. It's close, not the same.

Comment: @Programmer4000 You should post your HTML output, not the PHP

Comment: put handler inside a $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Comment: Also, where in the HTML do you put the `<script>`? Try putting it at the end of your `<body>`.

Comment: attach event listener after dom ready

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#next').on('click',function(){
        $('#content').hide();
    });
}
```

### [Demo: `on` function](http://jsfiddle.net/zq6Ec/8/)

But! As mentioned in comments, this can not work, if you have version < 1.7. `on` function had been added in 1.7 version of jQuery.

If you have jQuery version < 1.9 you can use `live` function.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#next').live('click',function(){
         $('#content').hide();
    });
}
```

### [Demo: `live` function](http://jsfiddle.net/zq6Ec/9/)

This function deprecated since 1.7 and it was removed in 1.9.

If you using jQuery < 1.7, you can use `live` function, but if not, you *should* use `on`, since `live` is deprecated.

Comment: It depends on the jQuery version - if he's using `live` perhaps he doesn't have `on`

Comment: Im using your code but is not doing anything still, im coding this in notepad and running it on mozilla

Comment: @Programmer4000 have you put the code inside a `$(function(){ ... })` block? jQuery _almost_ requires it

Comment: Run js fiddle, which will represent your problem.

Comment: @sharikov thanks for the help , i will see the demos

Comment: Make sure jQuery is included. I will edit it again now.

Comment: I've tried both functions , but they both are not working for me, do you think that it might be the browser?

Comment: I don't know what browser you use. What JS Debug tool do you use? Press CTRL+SHIFT+J and reload page with your scripts. Is there any errors?

Comment: there are no errors, the link is just doing nothing!

Answer (score 1):

put your script in document ready

```
$(function() {
 $('#next').live("click",function(){
      $('#content').hide();
 });
})
```

read more about it here:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("click","#next", function(){
            $("#content").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

using $(document).ready(function(){ will avoid error in IE 8.